# Unable to do condition check inside gitlab cicd

Tags: linux, bash, gitlab, cicd

I'm unable to test a condition in gitlab cicd. Here is the condition check I wanted to do.

count=`docker ps -aq | wc -l` && if [  "$count" -gt 0 ]; then echo "TESTING $count";fi

It works fine within bash shell but doesn't work inside gitlab-runner

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY 
    script: 
        - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY root@172.10.10.10" 
            docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS && 
            count=`docker ps -aq | wc -l` && if [  "$count" -gt 0 ]; then echo "TESTING $count";fi "
```

I get the following error `unary operator expected` any idea why?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.

I had to escape the special characters when using ssh.

```
deploy:
    stage: deploy
    before_script:
        - chmod 400 $SSH_KEY 
    script: 
        - ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i $SSH_KEY root@172.10.10.10" 
            docker login -u $REGISTRY_USER -p $REGISTRY_PASS && 
            count=\`docker ps -aq | wc -l\` && if \[  "\$count" -gt 0 \]; then echo "TESTING \$count";fi "
```